# Flashing code from IDE to microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

How does code download from PC to flash memory controller work? I mean what documents do IDE designers refer while designing this kind of software.

Are there any standard documents available for ST Microelectronics if one wishes to design a new IDE?

Comment: Why do you want to re(design) an IDE. Are you only looking for flashing the program to the MCU flash?

Comment: Yes.. I just wanna know the procedure for flashing the program to the MCU

Comment: One time, you have to use dedicated flash programmers..ST link for STMicroelectronics. If your question is specific about software upgrades, then there are plenty of options.

Comment: It depends on the controller manufacturer whether they make these documents generally available. Quite often they restrict them to companies that make development or programming tools.

Comment: ok. I understood this part. How do these flash programmers work?    Are there any drivers available for this? I mean I write my code for controllers in PC, then I build them. After building them, then I request my ide to download the code to my flash. Can you explain after that what happens? How do code gets transmitted to controller flash?

Comment: That depends on exactly which microcontroller is used. All are different, but essentially the micro is placed into a special flash write mode, and the data transmitted to it. Cannot be more specific without an exact part number.

Comment: You read the data sheets and app notes of course.  It's rarely an "IDE" that is responsible for loading code, or for that matter doing much of anything directly, rather it all gets delegated to helper programs which may either be subcomponents or fully independent command-line products that merely happen to be bundled and "driven" by the main IDE program.

Comment: @Umar, no, you do not need to use a "dedicated" programmer such as an stlink.  ST and pretty much every other vendor of ARM parts implements published variations on standard schemes.  Dozens of vendors offer compatible programmers, and you can make your own as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I still have to explore independent flash programmers. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the ST32X series MCU's and using a serial connection from your IDE/PC then read [this](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf) first, then the bootloader (over serial) [document](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/51/5f/03/1e/bd/9b/45/be/CD00264342.pdf/files/CD00264342.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00264342.pdf).

If you want to use other transfer Phy's then you need to do more research:
Application Notes:
– AN3154: CAN protocol used in the STM32 bootloader
– AN3155: USART protocol used in the STM32 bootloader
– AN3156: USB DFU protocol used in the STM32 bootloader
– AN4221: I2C protocol used in the STM32 bootloader
– AN4286: SPI protocol used in the STM32 bootloader

The "Flash Programmer" is just a piece of code in the client that offers a protocol over your selected Phy interface. Though this is simple stuff to look up, you really have no excuse for not being able to find it on your own.

Comment: Yes, though the bootloaders are far less commonly used than the JTAG/SWD (or for STM8, SWIM) interfaces.